# Trouble Pickling data into a subfolder

Tags: python, pickle

I have been trying to save a pickled piece of data into a sub folder, this is to make my quiz organised and neater

here is a sample of code to demonstrate my problem

```
import pickle

var1="test"
print(var1)
pickle.dump(var1,open("test.dat","wb"))
```

while I dump file, how do I change the location of the dump?
the file is located on my desktop in a file called "folder"

when leaving an answer please leave it in full altered code akin to how I have presented mine

Thank you :)

Comment: Just provide the full path to the file you want to write to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest change is to just supply the full path of the file you wish to write to.  I don't know what kind of system you're on, but here's how I'd do what you describe on my Mac:

```
import pickle

var1="test"
print(var1)
pickle.dump(var1,open("/Users/Steve/Desktop/folder/test.dat","wb"))
```

Comment: You don't know how to find the path to your desktop?  I think it's like Mac, where it's in your user directory.  Google for it.  I'm sure you'll find lots of examples.  It has nothing to do with what language you're programming.  When you find it, it's best that you use forward slashes even on Windows.  Python will convert them to backward slashes, and forward slashes are a lot easier to work with.

Comment: I have copied your code and it has given me an error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\Default\\Desktop\\Folder\\data.dat'

Comment: Try using single forward slashes.  If the path is right, it will work. - Your username is Default?

Comment: it worked !!!, my username and the slashes must have been the issue, thanks steve :)

Comment: Cool.  Please hit the check mark on this answer.  Nobody's been doing that for me lately.